# how to implement all Cloudify V2.7 shell command functionality through Cloudify V2.7 WebUI

Tags: cloudify

As of now,I am able to install and uninstall recipes  through WEBUI,but in Cloudify Shell we have lot of commands,how can we implement those commands functionality in WEBUI.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

In Cloudify 2.7*, there is one more option to invoke some commands from the WebUi:

You can invoke custom commands by selecting a service (i.e: focusing on it) and clicking on the wrench in the right-hand-side top corner and then writing the following in the dialog box : **commandName arg1 arg2** etc.

You can read more about custom commands [here](http://getcloudify.org/guide/2.7/developing/custom_commands.html).

Cloudify 3* will have many more features which will also be available from the WebUI, but we don't have an ETA yet.

HTH,

Tamir.